# cmake: handle third-party dependencies (include/lib) for different compilers/platforms

Tags: build, cmake, compilation, dependencies, cross-platform

I need to build C++ code for multiple platforms (Windows and Linux) 32 and 64 bit and multiple compilers (Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2017).

I use several third parties like: Boost, Tbb, Xerces and others.

How do I need to handle the fact that for Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2017, 32/64 bit etc. I need to use different versions of the third party includes and libraries?

Do I need to have something like 'if' statements inside CMakeLists.txt files where I specify different include/library paths and different library file names for different conditions?

Comment: Yes, you may use `if` for diffirentiate generator used for your project.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I need to handle the fact that for Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2017, 32/64 bit etc. I need to use different versions of the third party includes and libraries?

Actually, you don't need to do anything special to "handle this fact" %)
For example, you can download [Official prebuilt Boost binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/) (e.g. all-in-one package) and install it to, say default path `C:\local\boost`. Depending on selected toolset/VS-version `find_package(boost ...)` would seek for appropriate libraries with no additional efforts from your side. You just use the found libs w/ no `if`s.

Same for Linux. Say you need Ubuntu 18.04 amd64 and CentOS 7 x86. Just install the boost package if shipped w/ the distro, or build yourself if it doesn't. Then "use" it %)

> Do I need to have something like 'if' statements inside CMakeLists.txt files where I specify different include/library paths and different library file names for different conditions?

It sounds like the great misunderstanding of how CMake work %) In `CMakeLists.txt` of your project, you describe exactly one (Ok, a few, for multi-configuration generators) build. To make it happened your `CMakeLists.txt` have `find_package` for the needed third parties and they will find exactly one version of any dependency (Ok, I'm talking about normal projects now). Then using different OSes/environments you can build the required artifacts.

So, you just don't need "different" include/library paths. From your project's point of view, you just use `find_package` (for boost, & etc) and then use its results (imported targets of whatever). Because typically build happened inside a prepared environment like docker or vagrant image w/ all prerequisites installed inside and you just can't produce all your required builds using the only OS/environment, so you don't need to install different versions...

... to be precise you can... theoretically... but setting the cross-compiling environments much harder than to bake a docker/vagrant image of the target OS).

So for your case, you need to build the same sources few times:

- for Windows and different VisualStudio (2 versions * 2 architectures);
- for all Linux distributions and architectures (N-distros * 2 architectures).

Comment: Many thanks for this! Would find_package() work automatically for any third-party? What do I do with the third parties which have not been built with CMake? Do I need to add something to them in order find_package to work?

Comment: @AndreyRubliov Please check the docs for `find_package`. There are two ways to find a third-party package: _config mode_ (i.e. packages built w/ CMake) and _module mode_ (for non-CMake third parties). So, even non-CMake packages could be found by `find_package` w/ a little help from your side %)